# Encodable: Flattening structures

Tags: swift, codable

Let's say I have some type that has a JSON representation as such:

```
{
  "count": 3,
  "name": "Pianos",
  "type": "instrument",
  "id": 1,
}
```

Let's say that I want to represent this as a Swift object that looks like this:

```
struct SomeObject: Codable { // this is the object I'd like to represent
  let id: Int
  let details: SomeDetails
}

struct SomeDetails: Codable {
  let count: Int
  let name: String
  let type: String
}
```

Decoding this object is a no-brainer. But how would encoding work in this instance such that I can encode into a flat structure -- the same structure that I used to create this object and have shared in the JSON example above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But how would encoding work in this instance?

It just works:

```
struct SomeObject: Codable { 
    let id: Int
    let details: SomeDetails
}
struct SomeDetails: Codable {
    let count: Int
    let name: String
    let type: String
}
let someobject = SomeObject(id: 10, details: SomeDetails(count: 3, name: "ho", type: "hey"))
let json = try! JSONEncoder().encode(someobject)
```

If you insist on flattening it artificially, simply write your own `encode(to:)`, like this:

```
struct SomeObject: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let details: SomeDetails
    enum Keys : String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case count
        case name
        case type
    }
    func encode(to enc: Encoder) throws {
        var con = try enc.container(keyedBy: Keys.self)
        try con.encode(id, forKey: .id)
        try con.encode(details.count, forKey: .count)
        try con.encode(details.name, forKey: .name)
        try con.encode(details.type, forKey: .type)
    }
}
struct SomeDetails: Codable {
    let count: Int
    let name: String
    let type: String
}
let someobject = SomeObject(id: 10, details: SomeDetails(count: 3, name: "ho", type: "hey"))
let json = try! JSONEncoder().encode(someobject)
```

Comment: Wouldn't the encoding in this instance return the contents of `SomeDetails` under a `details` key? The goal is to get a flat structure out, just like the structure that came in.

Comment: I don’t know what you mean by any of that. The structure is _not_ “flat”. It can’t be. It’s a nest.

Comment: The idea is that I'd like to encode into a JSON representation that has the same keys that I decoded with -- your example above would have the keys `id` and `details`. I'm looking for a json with `id`, `count`, `name`, `type` keys. In other words, the `SomeDetails` structure is a client-side abstraction that doesn't need to exist when encoding the swift object back into its data representation

Comment: Well then write your own `encode(to:)` implementation. You must know how to do that, because you would presumably have had to write an `init(from:)` in order to turn the flat JSON into your nested structs.

Comment: Absolutely, that's the right answer. I'm experiencing a brain-fart at the moment. In any case, I'm going to post my answer to this question in case anyone else needs this in the future.

Answer (score 8):

An improvement for the previous answers. There is no need to manually encode or decode the other objects you can just forward the initialisers.

```swift
struct SomeDetails: Codable {
  let count: Int
  let name: String
  let type: String
}

struct SomeObject: Codable {
  enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case id
  }

  let id: Int
  let details: SomeDetails

  init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    id = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .id)
    details = try SomeDetails(from: decoder)
  }

  func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
    var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    try container.encode(id, forKey: .id)
    try details.encode(to: encoder)
  }
}
```

And for some added sugar you can use Swift 5s dynamic member lookup so that you can access those members nicely `object.name`.

```swift
@dynamicMemberLookup
struct SomeObject {
  ...

  subscript<T>(dynamicMember member: KeyPath<SomeDetails, T>) -> T {
    details[keyPath: member]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is reading this in the future (hi!), it's just a matter of stepping into your constructed type that boxes the values your abstracting.

```
struct SomeDetails: Codable {
    let count: Int
    let name: String
    let type: String
}


struct SomeObject: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let details: SomeDetails

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
    }

    enum DetailKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case count, name, type
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let topLevelContainer = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        let detailContainer = try decoder.container(keyedBy: DetailKeys.self)

        id = try topLevelContainer.decode(Int.self, forKey: .id)
        details = SomeDetails(
            count: try detailContainer.decode(Int.self, forKey: .count),
            name: try detailContainer.decode(String.self, forKey: .name),
            type: try detailContainer.decode(String.self, forKey: .type))
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var topLevelContainer = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try topLevelContainer.encode(id, forKey: .id)

        var detailContainer = encoder.container(keyedBy: DetailKeys.self)
        try detailContainer.encode(details.count, forKey: .count)
        try detailContainer.encode(details.name, forKey: .name)
        try detailContainer.encode(details.type, forKey: .type)
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that’s what I said. I think your use of two coding keys is a bit forced though.

Comment: Agreed, but it's a toy example; in reality this is a _gigantic_ json payload in a different problem space.